# RobinBuschmann/soap-typescript/soap-decorators Example

Tags: node.js, annotations, schema, decorator, node-soap

Can someone please give me a detailed example of RobinBuschmann/soap-typescript/soap-decorators Example. I am looking to create a wsdl xml for node-soap. The example given on github of RobinBuschmann/soap-typescript does not seem to work as is. I put the first three code snippets in a file called createWsdl.js and ran it with "node createWsdl.js" and I get an error. I suspect I am not doing the right thing. Can someone please help me or give me a detailed example that actually works.

Answer (score 1):

I used [node-soap](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap) and [soap-decorators](https://github.com/RobinBuschmann/soap-typescript) to communicate with Quickbooks. The following is from my `app.ts` file:

```
this.express.use(
    '/soap',
    soap(this.quickbooksController, {
        overrideRootElement: {
            namespace: '',
            xmlnsAttributes: [
                {
                    name: 'xmlns',
                    value: 'http://developer.intuit.com/'
                }
            ]
        }
    })
);
```

The controller is annotated like so:

```
import { SoapOperation, SoapService } from 'soap-decorators';
import { AuthenticateRequest, AuthenticateResponse } from './model/authenticate.interface';

@SoapService({
    portName: 'QBWebConnectorSvcSoap',
    serviceName: 'QBWebConnectorSvc',
    targetNamespace: 'http://developer.intuit.com/'
})
export class QuickbooksController {

    @SoapOperation(AuthenticateResponse)
    authenticate(data: AuthenticateRequest, res: (res: AuthenticateResponse) => any): void {
        res({ authenticateResult: { string: ['', 'NVU'] } });
    }
}
```

My request and response objects are decorated as XSD types:

```
import { XSDComplexType, XSDElement } from 'soap-decorators';

@XSDComplexType
export class AuthenticateRequest {

    @XSDElement
    strUserName: string;

    @XSDElement
    strPassword: string;
}

@XSDComplexType
class AuthenticateResult {

    @XSDElement({ type: 'string' })
    string: string[];
}

@XSDComplexType({ name: 'authenticateResponse' })
export class AuthenticateResponse {

    @XSDElement
    authenticateResult: AuthenticateResult;
}
```